# ggplot: Is there a way to add a color coded bar annotation to the right of the y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a plot like this,

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_violin()
p
```

What I want is to annotate the right with a color coded bar.  Is this possible? I included a hypothetical plot that I drew in.

[image]

Comment: Can you add `fill = Species` in `aes` `p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
geom_violin()`

Comment: @akrun no because the annotation would be independent of the species, else that would certiantly work.  So for example, I need 3-6 to be in brown which will cover both species toward the right.

Comment: One options would be to make use of `patchwork`. See e.g. my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073793/12993861).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotate function can do exactly as you indicate. The think to remember is that discrete scales have a continuous scale underneath and that the positions of discrete categories is `match(x, sort(unique(x))`, so that you bar should start around 3.5 for the iris dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_violin() +
  annotate(
    xmin = 3.5, xmax = 3.75,
    ymin = c(-Inf, 3, 6),
    ymax = c(3, 6, Inf),
    geom = "rect",
    fill = c("dodgerblue", "tan", "red")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you this is perfect!  I also realized that this could also be used to increase the number of block annotations and not limited to three as the example above.  ```ymin = c(-Inf, 3, 6, 8), ymax = c(3, 6, 8, Inf)```